# Hard hyphens in LuaLatex

Tags: line-breaking, luatex, unicode

Why does not the hard hyphen “‑” work in lualatex with the package `luainputenc` with option `utf8`?  With hard hyphen, I mean a hyphen, which prohibits the line to break directly after it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\begin{document}
Åsa‑Nisse
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not use luainputenc, use utf8 encoded files and fontspec. See my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`luainputenc` doesn't define a conversion for U+2011 (NON-BREAKING HYPHEN); you can do it yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2011}{\mbox{-}}

\begin{document}
Åsa‑Nisse
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or, as I would prefer, just use ``\mbox`` in those few instances where you don't want a break to occur with names such as "Åsa-Nisse".

Answer (score 5):

Use of `luainputenc` is deprecated. The documentation of `luainputenc` itself says:

> Input encoding management for LuaTEX, needed only for compatibility with old
>   documents. For new documents, using UTF-8 encoding and Unicode fonts is strongly
>   recommended. You’ve been warned!

UTF-8 support works out of the box with lualatex and fontspec if your files are utf8 encoded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    Åsa‑Nisse
\end{document}
```

Now to your question:
use the package extdash: `\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}`. This should be the **last** package you include, even after hyperref and bookmark.

[documentation](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools/doc/extdash.pdf)

You can then use the `\=/` command to indicate a non-breakable hyphen, the `\==` to indicate a non-breakable en-dash (`--`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% lots of packages here

% these are usually the last packages to load:
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
% very last package:
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}

\begin{document}
    Åsa\=/Nisse
    Maxwell\==Boltzmann\=/Deviation
    $x$\=/axis
\end{document}
```

If a word is a compound with hyphen, LaTeX by default only breaks at this hyphen, not at normally breakable places inside the words. `extdash` also deals with this problem. 
Of you use the commands `\-/` for a hyphen or `\--` for an en-dash LaTeX is also allowed to break inside of the words.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer, since it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Ill add the answer

Comment: I would normally user `fontspec` but I need to use “standard” fonts.

Comment: Latin Modern should be the _standard font_ and is the feault font that `fontspec` is loading

Comment: why do u need to use and what do you mean by standard fonts?

Comment: By “standard” font, I mean a font specified by somebody else, in this case `times`.  The good thing with this font is that it need not be installed in the computer that compiles the text nor be attached with the .tex file.

Comment: So how are using times without fontspec? And why not use `Tex Gyre Termes` with fontspec?